# Is there a shim for SVG transformOrigin in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, svg, shim

I'm trying to make an animation using SVG but IE doesn't like playing with transformOrigin.

It works in Chrome and Firefox. Try it in IE to see what I mean. Oh, and I don't want to depend on flash. I'll do canvas if required. Or even Shumway.

Relevant code

```
 var deg =360;
 Velocity.animate($('#inner').get(), {
              rotateZ: deg
            }, 1000)

<g id="inner" style="transform-origin: 81.0254859924316px 59.6874922621516px 0px;" data-bind="spinTriangle:true"
   id="g3359">
  <path
     d="m 68.010487,-6.3659557 24.050001,0 48.720002,89.4223967 -12.24,22.411139 -97.00001,0 -12.26999,-22.442889 z"
     id="inlight"
     style="fill:#a8a9ad;fill-opacity:1"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
  <path
     d="m 61.900487,27.282517 36.280001,0 18.150882,34.195786 -18.140882,33.492658 -36.320001,0.0106 L 43.56048,61.650506 Z"
     id="indark"
     style="fill:#5b5b5b"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
</g>
```

```js
    ko.utils.injectBinding = function(allBindings, key, value) {
      //https://github.com/knockout/knockout/pull/932#issuecomment-26547528
      allBindings.get = allBindings.get || getFallback;
      var has = allBindings.has;
      var get = allBindings.get;
      return {
        has: function(bindingKey) {
          return (bindingKey == key) || has.call(allBindings, bindingKey);
        },
        get: function(bindingKey) {
          var binding = get.call(allBindings, bindingKey);
          if (bindingKey == key) {
            binding = value;
          }
          return binding;
        }
      };
    };
    var router = {
      isNavigating: ko.observable(true)
    };
    var v = $.Velocity,
      q = Q;
    v.Promise = q.Promise;
    var template = $('img').html();
    var tan30 = 0.5773502691896258;
    ko.bindingHandlers.spinTriangle = {
      init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var deg = 0;
        var first = true;
        var spinFunc = function() {
          if (ko.unwrap(router.isNavigating) || first) {
            deg = deg ? 0 : 360;
            first = false;
            return v.animate(element, {
              rotateZ: deg
            }, 1000).then(spinFunc);
          }
        };
        ko.utils.extend(allBindings, ko.utils.injectBinding(allBindings, 'origin', {
          spinFunc: spinFunc
        }));
      },
      update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var origin = allBindings.get('origin');
        if (ko.unwrap(router.isNavigating)) {
          origin.spinFunc();
        }
      }
    };
    ko.bindingHandlers.roundRobin = {
      init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var forward = 1;
        var first = true;
        var arr = _.map($(element).children().get(), function(chEl) {
          return chEl;
        });
        arr.push(arr.shift());
        arr = _.zip($(element).children().get(), arr);
        arr = _.map(arr,
          function(item) {
            return [item[0].getBBox(), item[1].getBBox(), item[0]];
          });
        var spinFunc = function() {
          if (ko.unwrap(router.isNavigating) || first)
            forward = forward ? 0 : 1;
          first = false;
          return q.all(_.map(arr, function(item) {
            var original = item[0],
              target = item[1];
            el = item[2]
            if (forward) {
              return v.animate(el, {
                translateX: 0,
                translateY: 0
              }, 1000);
            } else {
              return v.animate(el, {
                translateX: target.x - original.x,
                translateY: target.y - original.y
              }, 1000);
            }
          })).then(spinFunc);
        };
        ko.utils.extend(allBindings, ko.utils.injectBinding(allBindings, 'origin', {
          spinFunc: spinFunc
        }));
      },
      update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var origin = allBindings.get('origin');
        if (ko.unwrap(router.isNavigating)) {
          origin.spinFunc();
        }
      }
    };

    ko.components.register('ultraspin', {
      viewModel: function(params) {
        this.scale = 2;
        if (params.viewModel)
          ko.utils.extend(this, params.viewModel);
        else
          ko.utils.extend(this, params);
      },
      template: template
    });
    debugger;

    ko.applyBindings()
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.2.2/velocity.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kriskowal/q/v1/q.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.7.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
<img>
<svg width="164" height="155">
  <g id="g3019" transform="translate(0,5),matrix(0.51365572,0,0,0.48391494,-0.10298261,3.0805811), scale({{scale}})">
    <g id="outer" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1.0581278,0,-8.5844007)">
      <path style="fill:#a8a9ad;fill-opacity:1" id="outlight" d="m 143.85049,9.0213601 15.99,27.3399999 -63.74,111.31 -32.11,0.01 L 0.20048956,36.37136 16.20049,9.0213601 Z" inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
      <path id="outdark" transform="matrix(0.79999999,0,0,0.80001581,0.20048956,0.96136007)" d="M 30.84375,28.96875 21.9375,44.5 l 68.84375,120.125 18,0.0312 L 177.625,44.5 168.75,29 Z" style="fill:#5b5b5b" inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
    </g>
    <g id="inner" style="transform-origin: 81.0254859924316px 59.6874922621516px 0px;" data-bind="spinTriangle:true" id="g3359">
      <path d="m 68.010487,-6.3659557 24.050001,0 48.720002,89.4223967 -12.24,22.411139 -97.00001,0 -12.26999,-22.442889 z" id="inlight" style="fill:#a8a9ad;fill-opacity:1" inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
      <path d="m 61.900487,27.282517 36.280001,0 18.150882,34.195786 -18.140882,33.492658 -36.320001,0.0106 L 43.56048,61.650506 Z" id="indark" style="fill:#5b5b5b" inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
    </g>
    <g data-bind="roundRobin:true" id="bolts">
      <path d="m 68.92049,47.50136 5.68,-9.72 11.12,0.14 5.42,9.56 -5.47,9.68 -11.26,0.01 z" id="bolt1" style="fill:#a8a9ad" inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
      <path d="m 54.04049,71.55136 5.63,-9.65 11.13,0.03 5.43,9.63 -5.34,9.6 -11.51,-0.05 z" id="bolt2" style="fill:#a8a9ad" inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
      <path d="m 89.26049,61.93136 11.19,-0.01 5.56,9.6 -5.4,9.5 -11.42,0.16 -5.38,-9.54 z" id="bolt3" style="fill:#a8a9ad" inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
</img>

<ultraspin></ultraspin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparently [GSAP](https://css-tricks.com/svg-animation-on-css-transforms/), hopefully we can get this into velocityjs as well solved this problem.